# how to add data from Employee table to user table in YII2 advanced

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I am working on my collage project i.e. Employee Management. I have Employee table in sql(crud is also generated from gii). only Admin is having rights to create Employee (there is no Signup).

My Problem: when I am creating employee then I am not able to save data in user table also, please help me to save data in both Employee and user table.

Thanks in advance

Update:

Below is the code:

```
public function actionCreate() { 
 $model1=new Employee; 
 $model2=new User; 
 if(isset($_POST['Employee']) && isset($_POST['User']))
 { 
   $model1->attributes=$_POST['Emoloyee']; 
   $model2->attributes=$_POST['User']; 
   $model1->save(); 
   $model2->save(); 
   echo 'data is saved in both tables'; 
 } 
 $this->render('create',array('model1'=>$model1,model2'=>$mod‌​‌​el2)); 
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you show the code for saving employee?

Comment: public function actionCreate()
    {
    $model1=new Employee;
    $model2=new User;
    if(isset($_POST['Employee']) && isset($_POST['User']))
    {
    $model1->attributes=$_POST['Emoloyee'];
    $model2->attributes=$_POST['User'];
    $model1->save();
    $model2->save();
    echo 'data is saved in both tables';
    }
    $this->render('create',array('model1'=>$model1,model2'=>$model2));

}

Comment: hi Chinmay code for my Employee Controller is as below:                                  
public function actionCreate() { $model1=new Employee; $model2=new User; if(isset($_POST['Employee']) && isset($_POST['User'])) { $model1->attributes=$_POST['Emoloyee']; $model2->attributes=$_POST['User']; $model1->save(); $model2->save(); echo 'data is saved in both tables'; } $this->render('create',array('model1'=>$model1,model2'=>$mod‌​el2)); }

Comment: You can edit the question and put your code there. It's difficult to read the code in the comments section.

Comment: Follow the instruction. This should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173865/how-to-insert-data-to-2-tables-i-e-employee-and-usermigrated-from-single-form

Comment: Follow the instruction. This should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173865/how-to-insert-data-to-2-tables-i-e-employee-and-usermigrated-from-single-form

Comment: You have a typo in this line `$model1->attributes=$_POST['Emoloyee']; ` Should be `$_POST['Employee'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example,

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Employee(); 
    $user = new User(); 

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $user->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if($model->save() && $user->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Record saved successfully.');
        } else {
            //var_dump($model->getErrors());
            //var_dump($user->getErrors());
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Record not saved.');
        }

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        var_dump($model->getErrors());
        var_dump($user->getErrors());
        die();
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but this code is also not working. I have migrated user table and also included class in the controller but the data is not inserting in the user table (only in Employee table) what would be the possible way.

Acutely in advanced yii2 users can login from user table so I want data from employee table to send to user table also.

if there is any other better way so that employee can be created and logged in

Comment: add this on your layout file for you to see output upon success or failure. `<?=yii\bootstrap\Alert::widget() ?>`

Comment: @Yuvrajverma. Check updated answer and it's proper and better way to ensure that model loaded and saved correctly. Refer official yii documentation.

Answer (score 0):

could be you have some validation problem

try check  this way

```
    ......

    $model1->attributes=$_POST['Emoloyee']; 
    $model2->attributes=$_POST['User']; 

    if ($model1->validate() && $model2->validate() ) {
        $model1->save(); 
        $model2->save(); 


    } else {
         $errors1 = $model1->errors;
         $errors2 = $model2->errors;
         var_dump($errors1);
         var_dump($errors2);
         exit();

    }
```

then just  for  debug  try using

```
    $model1->attributes=$_POST['Emoloyee']; 
    $model2->attributes=$_POST['User']; 
    $model1->save(false);
    $model2->save(false);
```

and check in db if the value are saved ..

Comment: I am not getting any validation problem,  have migrated user table and also included class in the controller but the data is not inserting in the user table (only in Employee table) what would be the possible way. Acutely in advanced yii2 users can login from user table so I want data from employee table to send to user table also. if there is any other better way so that employee can be created and logged in

Comment: i have update the answer  with a suggetsion for test .. let me know

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction given in below link . This should work

[how to insert data to 2 tables i.e Employee and User(migrated) from single form(Employee Create) and controller in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173865/how-to-insert-data-to-2-tables-i-e-employee-and-usermigrated-from-single-form)