# how to insert data to 2 tables i.e Employee and User(migrated) from single form(Employee Create) and controller in yii2

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

this is my create page
questions/create.php

`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'clinic_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Clinic::find()->all(),'id','clinic_name'),
        ['prompt'=> 'Select Clinic']
        )?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'user_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'mobile')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'is_active')->textInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

`

Employee Controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Employee();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

i have migrated user table and also included class in the controller but the data is not inserting in the user table (only in Employee table) what would be the possible way.

Acutely in advanced yii2 users can login from user table so I want data from employee table to send to user table also.

if there is any other better way so that employee can be created and logged in

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to to your create action

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  $employee = new Employee();
  $user = new User();

  if($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) AND $employee->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) AND Model::validateMultiple([$user, $employee])) {
    if($user->save(false) AND $employee->save(false))
    {
      return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
    else{
      return $this->render('create', [
      'employee' => $employee, 'user' => $user,
    ]);
    }

  }
  else {
    return $this->render('create', [
    'employee' => $employee, 'user' => $user,
    ]);
  }
}
```

Now in your form write the attribute and model which are related,like suppose first_name and last_name from Employee model and password ans email from user model then

```
<?= $form->field($employee, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($employee, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($user, 'user_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($user, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($user, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro i am able to save all the details in user table. My problem now is that i am not able to save password in hashed format, can u help me out

Comment: Check are u getting password in controller ?? If yes then above code will generate the hash code .     Otherwise use custom hash generate code like    $user->password =   Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);   $user->repeat_password =   Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);  .  Write this code just above if($user->save(false) AND $employee->save(false))